# python - make variable in file2 from variables in file1 and use in file1

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying like this:

File: a

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

from b import *

if obj1 is True:
    print('obj1 is true')
if obj2 is True:
    print('obj2 is true')
if obj3 is True:
    print('obj3 is true')
```

File: b

```
from a import *
obj1 = list1[0] + list2[0] < 7
obj2 = list1[1] + list2[1] < 7
obj3 = list1[2] + list2[2] < 7
```

output should be like as if it was all in one file:

```
'obj1 is true'
'obj2 is true'
```

Now i just get errors. I've tried all possible ways of doing the importing. Even like this:

File: a

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

from b import obj1, obj2, obj3

if b.obj1 is True:
    print('obj1 is true')
if b.obj2 is True:
    print('obj2 is true')
if b.obj3 is True:
    print('obj3 is true')
```

File: b

```
from a import list1, list2
obj1 = a.list1[0] + a.list2[0] < 7
obj2 = a.list1[1] + a.list2[1] < 7
obj3 = a.list1[2] + a.list2[2] < 7
```

It has something to do with that unseen '**name** = **main**' variable?
After this one I get a circular import error.
Is this not possible in python? Can somebody explain how to do it? Or if possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work that way, then just combine them, like so:

c.py

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]

obj1 = a.list1[0] + a.list2[0] < 7
obj2 = a.list1[1] + a.list2[1] < 7
obj3 = a.list1[2] + a.list2[2] < 7

if b.obj1 is True:
    print('obj1 is true')
if b.obj2 is True:
    print('obj2 is true')
if b.obj3 is True:
    print('obj3 is true')
```

Comment: doesnt seem possible... i tought the pyhton/reader wouldve swung the the other file on import command

Comment: @Adapt66 Can you (say) combine them into one file?

Comment: yeah i can i guess. but its just that the file will become like 60,000 lines or longer eventually. im kinda noob, maybe i shouldve been able to put all the variables into a function  or something. or im kinda average and it wasnt possible and its normal that it will become so long

Comment: so you have other functions? no problem. I will modify my answer.